Encapsuled closed vector subspace cannot have same finite codimension
I'm stuck in a elementary step in a proof of Fredholm alternative. I need to prove the following:
Let $X$ be Banach space on $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C} \}$,
Let $X_1, X_2$ be two closed vector subspace of $X$ with same finite codimension,
If $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ then $X_1=X_2$
I thought about using the fact that both $X_1$ and $X_2$ admits complemented subspaces with same dimension, and i tried to found an absurd on this dimension equality with the fact that if there is an element on the intersection, then all $\mathbb{K}-ray$ must be contained on it.

Let $S$ be a complement to $X_1$ in $X_2$, and let $S'$ be a complement of $X_2$ in $X$, so that:
$$X = X_2 \oplus S' = (X_1 \oplus S) \oplus S' = X_1 \oplus (S \oplus S')$$
$S'$ is of dimension $d := \operatorname{codim} X_2$, thus $S + S'$ is a complement of $X_1$ in $X$ of dimension $d + \dim S$.
But $d = \operatorname{codim} X_1$, therefore $d + \dim S = d$, thus $\dim S = 0$, and we get: $X_1 = X_2$.
